# Select the input value of a specific argument or the argument itself (argparse) to use as a class object

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

working with the following code:

```
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        description=textwrap.dedent('''\
            The Easy PSQL CLI tool
            --------------------------------
            Easily edit your postgres configuration,
            Add users, and create databases.
            * Uses default postgres user *
            '''))
    parser._positionals.title = 'Positional arguments'
    parser._optionals.title = 'Optional arguments'
    parser.add_argument("--add-user",
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        default='',
                        help="Add a new PostgrSQL user")
    parser.add_argument("--del-user",
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        default='',
                        help="Delete a PostgrSQL user")
    parser.add_argument("--passwd",
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        default='',
                        help="Assign the new PostgreSQL user a password")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args_dict = vars(args)
```

I need to take the input value of any of these arguments so that I can use them within a few objects later on. Preferably i'd like to turn them into variables, for example, make --add-user = dbuser as a variable.

On top of this, I would like to be able to say if the argument --add-user was used do this.. else --del-user do this, for example (some none-working code):

```
def dbuser(self):
        if get_args.args('add-user'):
            self.cur.execute(f"create user {self.user} with password '{self.password}'")
        if get_args.args('del-user'):
            self.cur.execute(f"drop user {self.user} ")
```

Comment: I don't see a question.  During debugging it's a good idea to print `args` or `args_dict` so you have a clear idea of what the parser read.  It will clear up any ambiguities about attribute names, e.g `args.del_user`.

Comment: If you leave the default as the default `None`, then `args.add_user is None` is a good test for an argument that wasn't provided. Nothing that the user can provide will give it a `None` value, so it's a clear default marker.

Comment: what do you mean you don't see a question? let's say that I enter the argument `--add-user test_user`, then I need to be able to say.. if I use argument `--add-user`, then insert the argument value into the `--add-user` command and follow that `if` statement, but if i enter the argument `--del-user`, the do the same for the `--del-user` if statement path. so my question is, how would I do that?

Comment: I would expect `args.add_user` to have the value 'test_user'.  Similarly in the `args_dict` - use 'add_user' as the key to retrieve the value from the dictionary.  Once you have `args` or `args_dict` you can fetch the value for an attribute, and use it as needed.